# Form validation: Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name password

Tags: ajax, forms, codeigniter, validation, authentication

I got this error in my firebug in a codeigniter site
Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name password
I have searched, found that the error pops up when there is and error in code, but nothing of the questions there is like mine.
could you help ?

**signin controller**

```
function do_login()
{
 $username = $this->input->post('username');
 $password = $this->input->post('password');

 if(!empty($username) && isset($username))
 {
 $this->form_validation->set_rules(
      'username', 'Your Username',
      'trim|required|xss_clean|max_length[20]|callback_username_check');

 $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password','trim|required||xss_clean|callback_password_check['.$username.']|min_length[4]|max_length[20]');

if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{

 echo json_encode(array('st'=>0, 'msg' => validation_errors()));
}
 else if(($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE))
{ 
echo json_encode(array('st'=>1));
}
function username_check($username)
{
$this->form_validation->set_message('username_check', ' is not regesterd!');
$checkVar=$this->user_model->check_user($username);
if($checkVar == true)
{return TRUE;}
elseif ($checkVar == false)
{return false;}
}   
function password_check($username,$password)
{
$this->form_validation->set_message('password_check', ' is not correct!');
$checkVar =  $this->user_model->check_pass($username,$password);
if($checkVar == true)
{return TRUE;}
elseif ($checkVar == false)
{return false;
}}}}
```

**user_model**

```
public function check_user($username) 
{
$this->query = $this->db->select('COUNT(*)')
    ->from('users')
    ->where(array('username'=>$username))
    ->limit(1)->get();
$query = $this->query->num_rows();
if ($query> 0){
    return true;
}
else{
    return false;
}
}
 public function check_pass($username, $password) 
{
$this->query = $this->db->select('COUNT(*)')
    ->from('users')
    ->where(array('username'=>$username, $password))
    ->limit(1)->get();
$query = $this->query->num_rows();
if ($query> 0){
    return true;
}
else{
    return false;
}
}
```

**ajax**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#frm').submit(function(){

$.post(
     $('#frm').attr('action'), 
     $('#frm').serialize(), 
     function( data ) 
     {
     if (data.st == 0)
     {
     $('#validation-error').html(data.msg);
     }
     else if(data.st == 1)
     {           var url = "home/"
     window.location.href = url;

     }
     }, 
     'json'
   );
 return false;   
  });


});

</script>
```

**form**

```
<?php echo form_open('signin/do_login', array('id'=>'frm')); ?>

                                <input type="text" id='username' name="username" size="15" placeholder="اسم المستخدم">                              

                                                                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" size="15" placeholder="كلمة المرور" >                              
                                                                        <div id="validation-error"></div>
                            <input type='submit' value="تسجيل الدخول">
                                        </form>
```

Comment: **Two `username` filed** in your form

Comment: In your html you have two inputs with the same name="username" and id= "username".

Comment: validate the 2 form elements "username" and let me what the current situation is .

Comment: same error @MustafaAdelELnagar

Comment: check argument of callback function and your function

Comment: What version of codeigniter are you using? I ask because `xss_clean` is not available in v3's form validation.

Comment: @Craig I think you can use it but you need to activate the security helper, and I have done that in the autoload configuration

Comment: an extra pipe `|` after required (**not the issue**) and a missing closing bracket here `callback_password_check['.$username.'|` (might be issue for sure) @HeshamWatany

Answer (score 5, accepted):

after searching and debuging I found that the problem was in this line

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password','trim|required||xss_clean|callback_password_check['.$username.']|min_length[4]|max_length[20]');
```

it should be

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password','trim|required|xss_clean|callback_password_check['.$username.']|min_length[4]|max_length[20]');
```

the problem was the " | " between required and xss clean
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You lost square bracket here, in controller

```
'trim|required||xss_clean|callback_password_check['.$username.'|min_length[4]|max_length[20]'
```

Should be

```
'trim|required||xss_clean|callback_password_check['.$username.']|min_length[4]|max_length[20]'
```

Comment: that **typo** should have been a comment and not an answers.

Comment: My reputation level doesn't allow me to comment, peace